# Is it possible to drop a RedShift auto materialized view?

Tags: redshift

I'm trying to alter a table definition, but it's dependent on a materialized view which is managed by RedShift Auto Materialization and not by us. So attempting

```sql
ALTER TABLE my_table
    ALTER COLUMN my_column TYPE VARCHAR(100);
```

Errors with

> [0A000] ERROR: cannot alter type of a column used by a materialized view

So I attempt to drop the materialized view

```sql
DROP MATERIALIZED VIEW pg_automv.auto_mv_53022635;
```

Which gives a permission error

> [42501] ERROR: permission denied for schema pg_automv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible, they are fully managed by AWS. The solution from AWS support is to turn off AutoMV and reboot to drop all AutoMV.

That is harsh.

Comment: I would think automvs are non schema bound to avoid this, I haven’t experienced it yet

Comment: @user433342 Materialized views don't have that option, they are always schema bound.